# Python 2.7/OpenCV 3.3 : capture frames from stereo cameras

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I am using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.3 and want to save images from stereo cameras at every defined frame count or after defined seconds. Like every 5th frame or after every 2 seconds frame should be stored in different folders like *cam1folder* and *cam2folder*. I am able to capture videos from both cameras and then used these videos to capture frames after predefined seconds. Codes for these are given below.

Code for videos capturing:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
out1 = cv2.VideoWriter('output1.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ret1, frame1 = cap1.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    out.write(frame)
    out1.write(frame1)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    cv2.imshow('frame1', frame1)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cap1.release()
out1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Code for frames capturing from both cameras after saving videos:

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
videoFile = "output.avi"
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)
success,image = vidcap.read()

videoFile1 = "output1.avi"
vidcap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile1)
success1,image1 = vidcap1.read()

seconds = 3
fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # Gets the frames per second
multiplier = fps * seconds
fps1 = vidcap1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # Gets the frames per second
multiplier1 = fps1 * seconds


while success:
    frameId = int(round(vidcap.get(1))) #current frame number, rounded b/c sometimes you get frame intervals which aren't integers...this adds a little imprecision but is likely good enough
    success, image = vidcap.read()

    frameId1 = int(round(vidcap1.get(1)))  #current frame number
    success1, image1 = vidcap1.read()

    if frameId % multiplier == 0:
        cv2.imwrite("right/rframe%d.jpg" % frameId, image) # stored in right folder
    if frameId1 % multiplier1 == 0:
        cv2.imwrite("left/lframe%d.jpg" % frameId1, image1) # stored in left folder


vidcap.release()
vidcap1.release()
print "Complete"
```

But what I want is real time capturing of images directly from videos without saving these videos but save captured images in two different folders. How to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to merge the 2 code snippets that you yourself have written.

In your first code snippet, when you run the `while` loop, you can maintain a common counter instead of separate counters for separate cameras. When your counter reaches the required value (5 frames, as per your question), you perform `imwrite` on the `frame` and `frame1` objects directly.

You do not need to intermediate with the `VideoWriter` object.
Your final code would look something like:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
multiplier = 5
frame_count = 0
while(True):
    frame_count += 1
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ret1, frame1 = cap1.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)  #show all frames
    cv2.imshow('frame1', frame1)

    if frame_count % multiplier == 0:
        cv2.imwrite("right/rframe%d.jpg" % frame_count, frame) #write specific frames 
        cv2.imwrite("left/lframe%d.jpg" % frame_count, frame1)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, It works perfectly. One thing I want to mention here is that frame_count++ is not supported by Python so I changed it to frame_count +=1 . 2nd, I want to know how you count the number of frames in above code without using CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES. As much I understand, Initial count is 0, while condition will be true and count will increase until frame_count % multiplier == 0 become true. Then, frame will be captured and again count will be 10. My query Is if count synchronous with frame rate? Means how we can say with increase in1 count, frame increased by 1?

Comment: The count is not synchronous with the frame rate. You've added a waitKey(1), which means that your loop will wait for 1ms between 2 iterations. Apparently `cap.read()' also puts the main thread on hold until a new frame is received

Comment: I think there is no time lag between left and right camera frame captured as both are actuated before cv2.waitKey(1). Is it true?

Comment: Yes. that's right. I would recommend that you increase the waitKey to 10